# Test case with empty object using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, nestjs

In the below code npm run test:cov gives coverage less than 100%. In index.html the single quotes are not covered which appears in yellow that the branch not covered.

```
 parsedResponse = (res: string): unknown =>
        const Length = Data.length;
        const Data = res.split('^^^');
              if (Length > 1) {
              const firstIndexArray = Data[0].split('^');
              let Name: string, topic: string, dob: string;
              Name = firstIndexArray[3] || '';//this shows yellow color that is branch not covered (single quote is not covered after or(||))
              Topic= secondIndexArray[0] || '';//this shows yellow color that is branch not covered (single quote is not covered after or(||))
              const secondIndexArray = Data[1].split('^');
              dob = secondIndexArray[1] || '';//this shows yellow color that is branch not covered (single quote is not covered after or(||))
       return {
        data: this.parsedResponse(result.success.data.string)
          };
```

Test case:

```
it('should return success', async () => {
      jest
        .spyOn(httpUtilMockService, 'get')
        .mockResolvedValue(EmptyRequestBody);
      try {
        const res = await service.details(EmptyRequestBody);
        expect(res).toMatchObject(SuccessResponseEmpty);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(
          await loggerService.logError('fake-message', { error: e.message })
        ).toBe(void 0);
      }
    });




 From the test data-
    SuccessResponseEmpty:
      "data": {
        "Name": '',
        "Topic": '',
        "dob": ''
      },
```

using the above testcase I can't achieve the coverage upto 100%.Please help me to understand that how to test these scenario's?

Comment: you need to call the `parsedResponse` function with an empty string in one of your test case so that when it `split('^^^')` or `split('^')` your indexes will be `undefined` then your `|| ''` statement will execute. hence it will be covered by your test.